# Ajax shopping cart

Tags: commerce

I installed several ajax carte modules but none have possibility to display shopping cart in there menu as on the image, if you add some products, shopping card displays number of added products

[image]

Comment: Hi, please remember that this is a Q+A site. You need to ask a specific question about the problem you're facing. Rather than just asking how to accomplish this whole broad feature, you need to break this down and describe exactly what you've tried, where you're stuck, and exactly what you need help with. Many thanks

Comment: Changed my question to more specific

Comment: is there any possible variants how can I do this task???

Answer (score 1):

I think this module will be helpfull
**[Commerce Popup Cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_popup_cart)**

Comment: in this module shopping cart doesn't refresh with ajax

Comment: [Ajax Basket Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_ajax_basket_link)

Comment: thanks for reply but it didn't refresh cart